# 3 displays, one GPU, passive DP, ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have a Radeon HD6850 card that I was using with Ubuntu 14. I had 3 dell monitors connected to this card and they worked great at 1600x1200. I had bought a Displayport to DVI adapter to get it working.

I recently bought an old Mac Pro 1,1 and moved my Video card and monitors to the new computer. And now OSX (Yosemite) will not run all 3 at once. It will do any 2 of them simultaneously (including through the DP adapter). but refuses to recognize the 3rd monitor.

Here is the thing. I'm pretty sure it's a passive adapter and from what I have read, it's not possible to have all 3 displays running without an active adapter. Its a RocketFish RF-DP49401. I just can't understand how it could have worked with Ubuntu. unless Ubuntu is using some kind of witchcraft?

Does anyone have any insight on this?